# Can I access the user input from Bokeh in a Flask app

Tags: python, flask, server, bokeh

I embedded the following example for user interaction from Bokeh in a Flask web app.

[tools_point_draw](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/examples/tools_point_draw.html)

It enables the user to create, drag and remove points when the point draw tool (upper right corner) is activated.

I'm trying to get the user generated data with this simple example for further processing.

Is this possible?
Can I sync the data back to the python server side?
If it is, could someone outline the steps how to do it?

code from webapp.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource, Column
from bokeh.models import DataTable, TableColumn, PointDrawTool, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.resources import INLINE

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def show_data():

    p = figure(x_range=(0, 10), y_range=(0, 10), tools=[],
               title='Point Draw Tool')
    p.background_fill_color = 'lightgrey'

    source = ColumnDataSource({
        'x': [1, 5, 9], 'y': [1, 5, 9], 'color': ['red', 'green', 'yellow']
    })

    renderer = p.scatter(x='x', y='y', source=source, color='color', size=10)
    columns = [TableColumn(field="x", title="x"),
               TableColumn(field="y", title="y"),
               TableColumn(field='color', title='color')]
    table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, editable=True, height=200)

    draw_tool = PointDrawTool(renderers=[renderer], empty_value='black')
    p.add_tools(draw_tool)
    p.toolbar.active_tap = draw_tool

    script, div = components(Column(p,table))

    return render_template('index.html', script=script, div=div, js_resources=js_resources,
                           css_resources=css_resources)

js_resources = INLINE.render_js()
css_resources = INLINE.render_css()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

And the code for the index.html

```
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>User Interaction</title>
        {{ js_resources|safe }}
        {{ css_resources|safe }}
        {{ script|safe }}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
            {{ div|safe }}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use another REST endpoint that takes parameters and have your Javascript make REST calls to fetch the response.

Comment: Thanks, could you specify what the appropriate parameters in this case are?